# The difference of parameters between “glm” and “optim” in R

Tags: r, optimization, glm

I’d like to know the difference of parameters(intercept, slopes) between “glm” and “optim” in R.
I think those predictions would be fine, but I can’t understand why those parameters are different. If it’s a misinterpretation, please give me some advice.

glm; -23.36, 46.72, 46.72

optim; -73.99506, 330.09424, 122.50453

```
#data
x1<-c(0,0,1,1)
x2<-c(0,1,0,1)
y<-c(0,1,1,1)

#glm
model<-glm(y~x1+x2,family=binomial(link=logit))
summary(model)
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)    -23.36   71664.47       0        1
#x1              46.72  101348.81       0        1
#x2              46.72  101348.81       0        1

round(fitted(model))
#0 1 1 1


#optim
f<-function(par){
eta<-par[1]+par[2]*x1+par[3]*x2
p<-1/(1+exp(-eta))
-sum(log(choose(1,y))+y*log(p)+(1-y)*log(1-p),na.rm=TRUE)
}
(optim<-optim(c(1,1,1),f))
$par
#-73.99506   330.09424  122.50453

round(1/(1+exp(-(optim$par[1]+optim$par[2]*x1+optim$par[3]*x2))))
#0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Any time your SE's are so much greater than your estimates, but especially so when using an exponential model, you need to ask whether you have a singular matrix or complete separation. It's a minor miracle that you get sensible predictions when your glm estimates are so huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer this in a  more general context. You have set up a logistic regression with *complete separation* (you can read about this elsewhere); there is a linear combination of parameters that perfectly separates all-zero from all-one outcomes, which means that the maximum likelihood estimates are actually *infinite* in this case.  This has several consequences:

- you will have seen a warning `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred` (this will usually, but not always, happen in this case)
- the standard deviations, which are based on the local curvature and depend on the assumption that the log-likelihood surface is quadratic, are ridiculous
- since the log-likelihood surface becomes flatter and flatter as you go toward extreme values of the parameter (slope approaching zero in the infinite limit), different optimizers will get essentially arbitrarily different answers, depending on the point where the surface happens to be flat enough for the algorithm to conclude that it has gotten sufficiently close to an optimum (= zero gradient). Not only different optimization methods (IRLS as in `glm` vs. the different `method` options in `optim`), but even the same optimization method on different operating systems, or even possibly built with different compilers, will give different answers.
- the `brglm2` package has methods for diagnosing complete separation (`?brglm2::detect_separation`), as well as methods for computing *bias-reduced* or *penalized* fits that will avoid the problem (by changing the objective function in a sensible way).

Comment: Very well written where you are touching the whole scope.

Comment: I didn't think your answer needed to be deleted ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. (actually, this data is "OR gate")